# Any Crux-like window manger for Ubuntu 20.04 and XFCE?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

I've been using Xubuntu (Ubuntu with XFCE) for many years, using the 18.04 LTS release almost since it was released.

My preferred GUI configuration is to set the Appearance to *Crux* (from the gtk2-engines package) and set the Window Manager theme to *Crux*.

The *Crux* configuration doesn't exist in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS because the latest version of XFCE drops support for GTK+ version 2.

I realize that it is unreasonable to ask the XFCE maintainers to restore GTK+2 support, but does anyone here know of Appearance and Window Manager themes (compatible with XFCE 4.14) that offer the following features:

- Scroll bars that still have up/down arrows at the ends of the bars
- Scroll bars where clicking in the space between the thumb and the edge of the bar performs a page up/down scroll instead of scrolling directly to the clicked position.
- Thick window borders, so it is easy to position a pointer for window resizing.  (Most themes these days seem to make the drag region only 1-2 pixels wide, which is difficult to click on)

The remaining Crux features (e.g. colors, fonts, button sizes/shapes) are less important to me.  If they aren't available, I can deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

For the scroll-bar behavior, I was able to find the *clearlooks-phenix-theme* package, but it still uses very thin window borders.

Answer (score 0):

Own gtk-style-definitions also in file:
~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
example for scrollbar width:

`.scrollbar.vertical slider,
scrollbar.vertical slider {
min-width: 12px;
}
.scrollbar.horizontal slider,
scrollbar.horizontal slider {
min-height: 12px;
}`

equivalent gtk-2 in file:
~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtk.css

`*{
-GtkRange-slider-width: 12;
-GtkRange-slider-height: 12;
}`

maybe you will find an idea for the window-border about these way

Comment: Interestingly, these options only adjust the scroll bar sizes for some applications (e.g. Mousepad) but not others (e.g. xfce4-terminal).  For the window borders, themes seem to prefer using bitmap images for everything instead of CSS.  Which means the theme probably needs to be altered to make the borders wider.

Comment: I'm not sure how your links to file managers have anything to do with GTK3 and XFWM themes.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought more to find the solution about the source of the two file-managers by github.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [theme](https://www.pling.com/p/1185760/) which I've written because I wanted to have those features you've described. (Also available as dark version)
If the borders of the windows are too thin, I might throw in an extra edition with extra wide borders. For xfce I left the borders size rather small, but the area, where you can drag is larger than usual.

Then there is the [Crux Theme](https://www.pling.com/p/1016230/) which is rather old and only for XFCE 4.2, but its XFCE WM theme should get you the right borders for the "classical" windows. The "modern" CSD windows are not supported.